# Gitlab CI variable is not resolved in 'before_script' of YML file

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, I try to use `plutil` command to save CI's variable into a `.plist` file in iOS project, as below code snipper showed.

Basiclly, I want to save CI variable to local file(.plist) and to use it from iOS project's test code. And this `Env_Jira_Variable` is one of the variables stored in Gitlab CI's variable settings.

```
before_script:
  - echo $PATH
  - source $HOME/.bashrc
  - echo $PATH
  - export BUNDLE_GITLAB__COM=x-access-token:$PACKAGE_DEPLOY_TOKEN
  - export Env_Jira_Variable=$Env_Jira_Variable
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install
  # Store CI variables to .plist file
  - plutil -insert Jira_Variable -string $Env_Jira_Variable ./iosApp/iosAppUITests/MyProject/variables.plist
```

But I got this error in Gitlab CI for command `plutil`

```
'Insert' and 'Replace' require a key path, a type, and a value2.
```

And if I change `$Env_Jira_Variable` to a plain text, the command could be success and related key and value are saved in .plist file. Our CI is using Mac M1 machine, and I think the format `$var` should be correct. And still unable to figure out what is the root cause, guys please give me any hint or advice.

Comment: Does the name match exactly, including upper and lower case of the letters? Also note that it is recommended to put double quotes around your variables to avoid problems with whitespace in them.

Comment: @knittl Ah, you are damn right. The variable key name in Gitlab CI was changed by my colleague recently. And I didn't even check it before this, thanks for your comment, and sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: [Please delete your question if it was caused by a typo.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320734/17676984)